# How to pass query parameters in react native WebSocket connection

Tags: react-native, websocket, expo

I have a server where I can make a WebSocket connection. When a device makes a WebSocket connection (when the app starts/splash screen), the server looks for the `query parameter` in the URL, which has the auth token of the user and if the token is correct, the connection is approved, else connection is rejected.

This is how the code looks on the react native client side:

```
const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${website}/?token=${value}`);
socket.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
    console.log('>>> socket on message:', messageEvent.data);
};
socket.onopen = function () {
    socket.send("hello world connection");
};
socket.onclose = () => {
    console.log('Socket disconnected');
};
```

This works fine in my iOS emulator, and the iOS emulator has a WebSocket connection to mine server. However, I have an android phone (testing via LAN), and when I open the app, I get an error saying:

> Unable to set ws://192.xxx.xx.xx/token=aut sfiseft2sefsefs..... as default origin header

But, if I remove the query param from the URL

```
const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${website}`);
```

This works fine, but since I cannot pass the token in the query params, I get an error from the server.

How can I pass query parameters to the WebSocket connection in android? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. Solve the issue by using encodeURI() before passing the url to WebSocket.

```
const uri = encodeURI(`ws://${website}/?token=${value}`);    
const socket = new WebSocket(uri);
```

This works for me.

Comment: This is not an answer at all. Please have a look at [how to answer properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).